# Hours, minutes, seconds since midnight method and output in table

Tags: java

Could someone check my math on my getTimeSinceMidnight method to see if it will return the hours, minutes, and seconds since midnight. I'll show an example of how i want the output to be. I have a TimeOfDay.java and a test.java for my output. Also, in the heading/directions it asks for the getTimeSinceMidnight to have enumerated number value types, and i'm not sure how to get those.

Heres my code:

```
//Write class for TimeOfDay
//Instace Data for: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
//Data for: hours, minutes, seconds, AM or PM
//Create appropriate getter and setter methods for each instace data
//Write method called getTimeSinceMidnight to return number of hours or seconds
//since midnight
//This method should accept enumerated data types:HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS
//should return an int value

import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TimeOfDay
{
  //declare variables
  private int hours, minutes, seconds, SSM, MSM, HSM;
  private String ampm;

  //TimeOfDay constructor

  public TimeOfDay(int h, int m, int s, String ap)
  {
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    seconds = s;
    ampm = ap;
      if (ampm.equals("PM"))
      {
        h = hours + 12;
      }
      else
      {
         ampm.equals("AM");
      }
  }

  //Setter Methods for instance data

  public void setDay(String d) {day = d;}
  public void setHours(int h) {hours = h;}
  public void setMinutes(int m) {minutes = m;}
  public void setSeconds(int s) {seconds = s;}
  public void setAmPm(String AmPm) {ampm = AmPm;}

  //Getter Methods for instance data

  public String getDay() {return day;}
  public double getHours() {return hours;}
  public int getMinutes() {return minutes;}
  public int getSeconds() {return seconds;}
  public String getAmPm() {return ampm;}

  //Method to return the HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS since midnight

  public int getTimeSinceMidnight()
  {
    SSM = hours * 3600;
    return SSM;
    MSM = minutes + hours * 60;
    return MSM;
    HSM = hours + (minutes * 60) + (seconds/60) * 60;
    return HSM;
  }
  //toString Method

  public String toString()
  {
    String s;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0#");
    s = df.format(hours) + ":" + df.format(minutes);

    s = String.format("%1$2s", hours) + ":";
    return s;
  }
}
```

Here is my test program:

```
//Test program c
//output the amount of time since midnight
//output as hours, minutes, seconds
//hours output should be in format of ##.### (use double variables for this)
//minutes and seconds just output as integers
//use only integers for your variables involved in minutes and seconds calculations
//Read in (no prompts) a time of day, end when user types QUIT or quit
//Time of day will look like: 4:15:00 PM



import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class testTimeC
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    String ampm;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    s.useDelimiter(":|\\s+"); // helps the scanner know when numbers end - :

    while (s.hasNextLine())
    {
      hours = s.nextInt();
      minutes = s.nextInt();
      seconds = s.nextInt();
      ampm = s.nextLine().trim(); // remove leading spaces from " AM" or " PM"
      System.out.println("hours = " + hours);
      System.out.println("minutes = " + minutes);
      System.out.println("seconds = " + seconds);
      System.out.println(ampm);
      //add the remaining printlns if you wish to see the rest of the data
    }
  }
}
```

The output should look as such for the test program:

Corresponding Output

```
 TIME          HOURS   MINUTES    SECONDS
 4:15:00 PM   16.250       975      58500 
11:59:00 PM   23.983      1439      86340 
 8:00:10 AM    8.000       480      28810 
12:45:20 PM   12.750       765      45920 
 2:37:00 AM    2.617       157       9420
```

So to dumb it down into 2-3 questions:

1. Is my getTimeSinceMidnight math correct?
2. Do i need to use enumerated number types or will the variables i
   have asigned work for me?
3. How exactly would i make my output into the corresponding output i need above?

Thanks!!

Comment: "Is my getTimeSinceMidnight math correct?" - does it match the expected results? If so, then it is correct.

Comment: Even if the math is correct, `MSM = minutes + hours * 60;` and the following lines won't ever execute as they are after the `return` statement. (not sure if it will even compile)

Comment: As Amongalen said, when you run the program what do the actual results look like ?

Comment: @Amongalen It _shouldn't_ compile, but he literally does not use the method anywhere so it looks like it will compile.  If he tries to call it somewhere then it won't compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, yea i forgot to move my return statements in the getTimeSinceMidnight method, they should all be at the end! I have all the math for time calculation, but no idea how to put that in enumerated format, so thats why the method may look weird. I also haven't called the method as i need to output this time information in a table, and am not sure how to do such output.